# Knapsack Problem with Multiple Properties

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, knapsack

### Problem Description

I have many examples (say $N$) to choose from to train my machine learning model. However, I could only select $n \ll N$ based on a set of $K$ attributes $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_k\}$ already measured for the dataset.

Now I would like to find these $n$ samples so that some measure (for example, sum) of the **each** of the $K$ columns are maximized.

### What I Tried

This looks like a knapsack problem but with multiple attributes. However, direct Google search does not seem to give me a lot of relevant results as I am looking for an existing software package that could solve this problem (or perhaps its relaxed version).

### Note

Cross-posted at [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4721933/488804) with 200 bounty points.

Comment: Maximizing the sum of each attribute (column) is not possible (barring a major coincidence where the solution maximizing one attribute maximizes all of them). You have a multiobjective problem. I added the tag "multi-objective-optimization". Search for posts with that tag to get some idea of the range of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

First, let $x_i=1$ if the $i$th example is picked, where $i \in \{1, 2, …, N\}$, and $x_i=0$ otherwise.

If you want to maximize the sum of ALL the elements, simply a knapsack problem with non-varying weights suffices.

$$max \sum_i (\sum_k a_{ki}) x_i$$

Subject to

$$\sum_i x_i \leq n$$

This can trivially solved by picking the first $n$ elements ranked by the sum of its attributes.

If instead you want to maximize the minimum of the sum of each attribute, you can introduce integer variable $z$ to solve

$$max \; z$$

Subject to

$$\sum_i x_i \leq n$$

$$\sum_i a_{ki} x_i \geq z, \; \forall k $$

Comment: In both models, I think $a$ should have both $i$ and $k$ as subscripts. In the second model, you do not need the $y_k$ variables. You can just require $\sum_i a_{k,i} x_i \ge z.$

Comment: @prubin Thank you for your corrections.